# How to Disable some of the method in asmx webservices

Tags: c#, asmx

For some reason I wanted to disable some of the method from the ***.asmx** web services. Those methods could be in used in future so i don't wanted to remove or delete, but only wanted to disable.

I also wanted to hide those method from the documentation when the webservice is accessed through URL like `https://someexamplesite.net/webservice1.asmx`, also I wanted to restrict the request to that method if the request is send from some tools like `SOAPUI` or `Fiddler` using the url something like
`https://someexamplesite.net/webservice1.asmx?op=method1`

I have multiple web services let say

**Webservice1.asmx**

```
[WebMethod]
public string Method1()
{
  //only able to use this method
}
[WebMethod]
public string Method2()
{
  //disable the method2
}
[WebMethod]
public string Method3()
{
   //disable the method3
}
```

**Webservice2.asmx** so on..

Similarly, for `Webservice2.asmx` `Method1()` should be able to invoke by client but `Method2()` should be disable for invoking and also it should not be appear on Webservice documentation.

I thought of commenting the method, but if there is some other proper way to disable that?

Please provide some suggestion for how to do that properly.

Comment: Please add a [mcve],.

Comment: Make the signature `Private` instead of `Public` or take the `[WebMethod]` off?

Comment: @Steve Making those method private is not appearing on List of Operation. But not sure if that can be invoked from client application if my web services is already referenced on that application.

Comment: It shouldn't be - but if you want to be 100% sure, comment the `[Webmethod]` decorator and it should be fine.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the quick help i will do accordingly.